# in C# using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel Is there a way to collect the data from a row without looping through each cell of the row?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, excel-interop

I'm trying to collect the data from each row of an excel worksheet and turn it into a coma-separated string for comparison using a dictionary.

I'm looking for a way to collect each row's data without looping through each cell of each row to reduce time complexity.

is there a way to achieve something similar to the following?

```
Dictionary<string, int> cwData = new Dictionary<string, int>();
string key = "";
foreach (Range row in cwRange)
{
                
    key = string.Join(",", row.Value);
    cwData.Add(key, row.Row);
    print(key);

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760591/convert-excel-range-to-c-sharp-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me, I'd use the power of the tool you're working with to do the concatenation for me.

This is a fairly light example and would need a little more work ...

```
static void ConcatenateRange()
{ 
    var xlApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    var xlWorkbook = xlApplication.Workbooks.Open("C:\\temp\\Data.xlsx");

    try
    {
        var xlWorksheets = xlWorkbook.Worksheets;
        var xlWorksheet = (Worksheet)xlWorksheets.Item[1];

        var lastCell = (Range)xlWorksheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset[1, 1];
        lastCell.Formula = "=TEXTJOIN(\",\",TRUE,A1:O15)";

        var concatenatedString = lastCell.Value;

        Console.WriteLine(concatenatedString);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        xlWorkbook.Saved = true;

        xlWorkbook.Close();
        xlApplication.Quit();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

... but basically, it opens a workbook, finds the last cell for the sheet you're working with, offsets that last cell by 1 row and 1 column (obviously this assumes that the entire worksheet isn't used) and then throws in a `TEXTJOIN` formula to do the work without having to loop.

This is the worksheet ...

[image: Worksheet]

... and this is the result (in console output) ...

[image: Console]

The last point to make is, it sets the saved status of the workbook to true and then simply closes it.  This ensures no changes are made.